# Multiple discount codes can be used in one order during checkout?

Tags: shopify

Please can clarify in Shopify checkout Multiple discount codes multiple times can't be used in one order??. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You are 100% correct. You cannot and never have been able to, and likely never will be able to use more than one discount code in a Shopify checkout. Of course, whatever, that could change one day.

Answer (score 0):

From 21st September, 2022 it'll be possible !

Comment: Also you're still able to use LineItem scripts(if you have a Shopify Plus plan) with discounts

Comment: Hi Max, How do you say that? If they going to implement means its possible in the Shopify plan or do we have to upgrade to Shopify Plus?

Comment: this feature only opened for Shopify Plus Plan, so right - you should upgrade to Plus plan to get Script Editor app.

Comment: But there're a lot of apps which let you to use/enter multiple discount codes

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).